# Maui Preferences: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Int32'

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

In my MAUI application, I created a simple class where I have all the `UserSettings`.

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm;
public class UserSettings
{
    public long DefaultDictionary
    {
        get { return Preferences.Get(nameof(DefaultDictionary), 0); }
        set { Preferences.Set(nameof(DefaultDictionary), value); }
    }

    public void CleanValues()
    {
        Preferences.Clear();
    }
}
```

In the property `DefaultDictionary` I save a simple `long` number. When I read the value I get this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Int32'

[image]

Is it possible to save numbers? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `Preferences.Get(nameof(DefaultDictionary), 0)` value is Int32 not long. The `0`'s default type is Int32. You need to convert it to long. Such as:

```
public class UserSettings
{
    public long DefaultDictionary
    {
        get { return Preferences.Get(nameof(DefaultDictionary), long.Parse("0")); }
        set { Preferences.Set(nameof(DefaultDictionary), value); }
    }

    public void CleanValues()
    {
        Preferences.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought `0` is always valid.

Comment: Why going through the hassle of using string parsing? Just use `0L`, no?

Comment: I agree with Nerpson - I can't upvote this answer because that is a terrible way to get a long 0. Even if it was an int variable, the correct fix would be `(long)myint`, not string parsing.

Comment: @Enrico *"I thought 0 is always valid. "* What's missing, is telling c# what **type of value** is being retrieved. See my comment on Peter's answer for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the default to a 0L.

```cs
public long DefaultDictionary
{
    get { return Preferences.Get(nameof(DefaultDictionary), 0L); }
    set { Preferences.Set(nameof(DefaultDictionary), value); }
}
```

Comment: Note: if the default was from a variable `int mydefault`, the solution would be `Preferences.Get(nameof(DefaultDictionary), (long)mydefault);`. Or alternatively, `Preferences.Get<long>(nameof(DefaultDictionary), mydefault);`. All of these are ways of selecting the `Get<long>` version of `Preferences.Get<T>`.